# What interpolation technique does Matlab plot function use to show the data?

Tags: matlab, plot, interpolation

It seems to be very basic question, but I wonder when I plot x values against y values, what interpolation technique is used behind the scene to show me the discrete data as continuous? Consider the following example:

```
x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y)
```

My guess is it is a Lagrangian interpolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Lagrangian interpolation with 200 equally spaced points would be an incredibly bad idea. (See: [Runge's phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon)).

The `plot` command simply connects the given (x,y) points by straight lines, in the order given. To see this for yourself, use fewer points:

```
x = 0:pi/4:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

No, it's just a linear interpolation. Your example uses a quite long dataset, so you can't tell the difference. Try plotting a short dataset and you'll see it.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB's `plot` performs simple **linear interpolation**. For finer resolution you'd have to supply more sample points or interpolate between the given x values.

For example taking the sinus from the [answer of FamousBlueRaincoat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28378567/1797098), one can just create an x vector with more equidistant values. Note, that the linear interpolated values coincide with the original plot lines, as the original does use linear interpolation as well. Note also, that the `x_ip` vector does not include (all) of the original points. This is why the do not coincide at point `(~0.8, ~0.7)`.

[image]

## Code

```
x = 0:pi/4:2*pi;
y = sin(x);

x_ip    = linspace(x(1),x(end),5*numel(x));
y_lin   = interp1(x,y,x_ip,'linear');
y_pch   = interp1(x,y,x_ip,'pchip');
y_v5c   = interp1(x,y,x_ip,'v5cubic');
y_spl   = interp1(x,y,x_ip,'spline');

plot(x,y,x_ip,y_lin,x_ip,y_pch,x_ip,y_v5c,x_ip,y_spl,'LineWidth',1.2)
set(gca,'xlim',[pi/5 pi/2],'ylim',[0.5 1],'FontSize',16)

hLeg = legend(...
    'No Interpolation','Linear Interpolation',...
    'PChip Interpolation','v5cubic Interpolation',...
    'Spline Interpolation');
set(hLeg,'Location','south','Fontsize',16);
```

By the way..this does also apply to `mesh` and others

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:2:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;

figure
mesh(Z)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responses, the concept is linear interpolation, i think it would be good idea if matlab plot function had an argument about the interpolation method.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, @hamiddashti - I was suprised, when I did not find something alike in the `plot` docs.